# Implementing Graph Program

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I was trying to implement graph via adjacency matrix using arrays. 
But I stumbled upon an issue
My graph has vertices like 5,7,3,6 (they are not in order to map to array index).
I know to implement then is they are same as array indices.
I thought to make another lookup array, with vertices and array indices.

But that will make it have high time complexity. 
I tried searching on Google too, but all I found was for array indices.

Any suggestion will be helpful adjacency list or matrix

Comment: The details of the solution depend on the input format. But in general remapping the vertex numbers takes very little time, and only needs to be done once at program startup.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Any language is fine. I am was using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two straight-forward options:

---

**1. Vertex Tagging**

For each vertex you read, identify it with a tag. In your case:

```
vertex | tag
-------|-----
  5    |  0
  7    |  1
  3    |  2
  6    |  3
```

In order to have a good performance doing this, you should map the vertices with a `unordered_map` (or hash map) in direct and inverse order, so that when you are given a vertex, you can get its tag in O(1) with `forward[vertex]` and when you are given a tag, you can find its vertex in O(1) with `backwards[tag]`:

```
int tag = 0;
unordered_map<int, int> forward, backwards;

for(int v : vertices){
    forward[v] = tag;
    backwards[tag] = v;
    tag++;
}
```

Lastly, represent your graph as an adjacency list just as you know, using the tags, that are 0, 1, ..., n - 1.

---

**2. Direct Mapping**

This is easier. Instead of using an array for your vertices, use an `unordered_map` that maps a vertex value to its adjacency list:

```
unordered_map<int, vector<int>> G;

for(int v : vertices){
    G[v] = vector<int>();
    vector<int> &adj = G[v];
    //add all nodes adjacent to v in adj
}
```

If you want to iterate through the adjacency list of 5, just do:

```
vector<int> &adjList = G[5];

for(int v : adjList){
    //stuff
}
```